# Libgdx and Google In-App-Purchase result

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, libgdx

I followed these [instructions](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) to integrate both Libgdx and native android code using ActionResolver interface. I have no problem calling the Android method from the Libgdx part of my code. But I am hitting a dead end when I am trying to intergrate Google IAP with Libgdx. According to TrivialDrive example, it uses mPurchaseFinishedListener (outside of calling method).
My question is: how do I pass this IAP resultcode back to Libgdx since the listener is outside the calling method? Currently, purchase process went through, but the libgdx part of my code is not being "informed" of the purchase status/result.
This is my code:

Any help is much appreciated.

ActionResolver:

```
public interface IActionResolver {

public int requestIabPurchase(int product);

}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements IActionResolver {

// Debug tag, for logging
static final String TAG = "greatgame";

// Does the user have the premium upgrade?
boolean mIsUpgraded = false;

// SKUs for our products: the cat, all, or pow
static final String SKU_UPGRADE = "android.test.purchased";

// (arbitrary) request code for the purchase flow
static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;

// The helper object
IabHelper mHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;

    initialize(new Catland(this), cfg);
}

void iAbStartup() {

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "some key";

    // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating IAB helper.");
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

    // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener
    // will be called once setup completes.
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) {
                return;
            }

            // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
}

// Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        // Do we have the SKU_UPGRADE upgrade?
        Purchase thisUpgrade = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_UPGRADE);
        mIsUpgraded = (thisUpgrade != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(thisUpgrade));
        Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsUpgraded ? "Upgraded" : "Free"));
        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
        runPurchaseFlow(submitProduct);
    }
};

// Run real purchase flow
public void runPurchaseFlow(int product) {
    Log.d(TAG, "runPurchaseFlow");

    /* TODO: for security, generate your payload here for verification. See the comments on
     *        verifyDeveloperPayload() for more info. Since this is a SAMPLE, we just use
     *        an empty string, but on a production app you should carefully generate this. */
    String payload = "";

    if (product == 1) 
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_UPGRADE, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);

}

// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
            return;
        }
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_CAT)) {
            // bought the upgrade!
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase Upgrade. Congratulating user.");
            mIsUpgraded = true;
    // how do i pass this result to the libgdx?

        }
    }
};

/** Verifies the developer payload of a purchase. */
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
    String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
    return true;
}

@Override
public int requestIabPurchase(int product) {

    iAbStartup();

    return 0; // how do i get the result from mPurchaseFinishedListener?
}

}
```

PurchaseScreen

```
result = greatgame.actionResolver.requestIabPurchase(1);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to return the result from requestIabPurchase() - the only methods of doing so would block for a long time. The best way, in my opinion, would be to create a listener interface of your own that your LibGdx project implements, and pass that into your request interface. For example:

In your libGdx project somewhere:

```
interface PurchaseCallback {
    public int setPurchaseResult(int result);
}
```

ActionResolver:

```
public interface IActionResolver {
    public int requestIabPurchase(int product, PurchaseCallback callback);
}
```

In PurchaseScreen, implement PurchaseCallback:

```
@override
public int setPurchaseResult(int result) {
    // Yay! I have a result from a purchase! Maybe you want a boolean instead of an int? I don't know. Maybe an int (for the product code) and a boolean.
}
```

...and pass whatever is implementing PurchaseCallback (I'm assuming your PurchaseScreen does itself):

```
result = greatgame.actionResolver.requestIabPurchase(1, this);
```

Finally, hook it all up in MainActivity:

```
PurchaseCallback mCallback = null;

mPurchaseFinishedListener = ... etc. etc.
.
.
.
   if (mCallback != null) {
       mCallback.setPurchaseResult(0);
   }
.
.
.

@Override
public int requestIabPurchase(int product, PurchaseCallback callback) {
    mCallback = callback;  // save this for later

    iAbStartup();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you should call PurchaseCallback.setPurchaseResult() everywhere that mPurchaseFinishedListener has `return`, not only at the line `// how do i pass this result to the libgdx?` - otherwise, you will never know if a purchase failed or is just taking a really long time.

Comment: Right, didn't think of that. Deleted my answer.

Comment: Thanks @logan-pikcup. I see you point. I tried your code however, it seems that my PurchaseScreen give me this error `The method requestIabPurchase(int, PurchaseCallback) in the type ActionResolver is not applicable for the arguments (int, new InputListener{})`. the 2 quick fixes suggested by ecplise 1 `Change method 'requestIabPurchase(int, PurchaseCallback)' to 'requestIabPurchase(int, InputLestener)'`; 2 `Create method 'requestIabPurchase(int, InputLestener)' in type 'ActionResolver'`. What should i do next?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - add `implements PurchaseCallback` to the class you're passing to `requestIabPurchase` (I assumed you were passing `MainActivity` to `PurchaseCallback`).