# Libgdx + Android In-App Purchase

Tags: android, libgdx, in-app-purchase

I want to use Google In-App billing for my Android Apps (using Libgdx). By default, It is a free apps for everyone. In that I have used InAppPurchase for purchasing the coins.

I have a read on official Google's Billing site but I have no idea how to link it to Libgdx. The Official Libgdx Site doesn't really provide any clear instruction and explanation.

As at today, I still have no idea on how to link both Libgdx and In-App Billing. Furthermore, where is the information being stored (is it in the preference file?) when user purchased the unlocked item? I have absolutely no idea.

It will be great if someone lead me to the right path. Thank in advance.

Comment: Here you can find some useful links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921146/libgdx-android-in-app-simple-tutorial

Comment: actually i see this link, but i want any sample or tutorial for it

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use gdx pay([link](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay)).

My preference, however, is doing all of this myself.

Before adding any code, I would like to express the fact that this can be done with anything you need to call OS specific code.

Before starting, make sure you have the .aidl for in app billing, and have the appropriate permissions.

First, we need an interface in the core:

```
public interface IabWrapper {
    boolean connect();//Connect to the IAB framework - return success or failure 
    Result buyProduct(String SKU, boolean consumeInstantly);//Buy the product, and figure out whether or not to consume it instantly. Return success or fail
    //You get the idea at this point. Add more methods to handle subscriptions (if applicable), etc
}
```

And result:

```
public class Result {
    boolean purchaseSuceeded;//If the purchase succeeded
    String sku;//The SKU
    boolean didConsumeSucceed;//If consumable, did it succeed. Just set it to "true" if it doesn't cusome
    //Here you can add constructors, other data, whatever you need
}
```

Now, in your Android project you create a class that implements the IabWrapper. Add a constructor with everything you need for the IAB. You also add this on any other platforms you use.

At this point, you should have:

- A class called IabWrapper in the **core** module
- A class called Result in the core module
- A class implementing IabWrapper in the Android module

The advantage by doing it like this is that you now can set up in app billing as per the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) or any other documentation/tutorial you find. Convert it into the methods you add in IabWrapper, and you can follow the Android docs to implement it.

Now, once you have created the iab code in the Android project, you need to open the class you initialize in teh core project. IN there, you add a constructor with either:

- An argument for the wrapper
- A wrapper argument with all the other wrappers you have (if you have any) (I use this method, but I have 3-4 wrappers and I expect to end at about 6 when I'm done with my game)

And of course, you need to pass the wrapper from the desktop project, ios project, android project or any other projects you have.

Because it is an interface, you define it in the constructor as `IabWrapper` and it is up to each individual platform to supply the class implementing the interface with the appropriate method for handling in app purchases.

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461820/libgdx-and-google-in-app-purchase-result?rq=1) I also recommend you add a callback class for checking if there has been an update in in app purchases. Android is async in internet calls unless you change (I have forgotten what, but there is a field that allows you to make internet calls on the main thread. but it often results in ANR, as you block the main thread).

So, in your render you add somethign like this:

```
if(purchaseRequested && !callback.response()){
     //What can you do, there is a purchase requested you are waiting for.
}else if(purchaseRequested && callback.response(){
     //This is where you would process the response, add whatever is purchased, save, unlock content, whatever the in app purchase does
}
```

---

If you have no clue as to how to handle the Android OS, or think this method looks overly complicated, I recommend you use gdx pay instead.

---

And to take up the thing I said at the start, this technique can be applied to **anything** where you need OS specific things. You create an interface in core, override it in the other projects and pass it to the core class. Then make calls to the wrapper and, because it is an interface, it makes the call to the class that implements the class